# Markers not Show on maps in React Native

Tags: google-maps, react-native, google-maps-markers

Hi I get an array of loaction an I want to add markers in map

I use this code , camera is ok , when I use first object of array marker add but when want to add all markers did not added!!

This is may code:

```
<View >
  <MapView
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    onLayout={this.onMapLayout}
    style={styles.map}
    initialRegion={{
      latitude: this.props.data ? this.props.data[0].YPOINT : '',
      longitude: this.props.data ? this.props.data[0].XPOINT : '',
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    }}

  >

    {this.state.isMapReady && this.props.data.map((value, index) => {

       { console.log("index is : " +index+"\n Ypoint : " + value.YPOINT+ " Xpoint : " + value.XPOINT)}
      <Marker
        key={index}
        coordinate={{
          latitude: value.YPOINT,
          longitude: value.XPOINT,
        }}
      />
    })}

  </MapView>
</View>
```

My code is wrong?

Thank for helping.

Comment: Hi Amir, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return from `map` like,

```
{this.state.isMapReady && this.props.data.map((value, index) => {
      console.log("index is : " +index+"\n Ypoint : " + value.YPOINT+ " Xpoint : " + value.XPOINT)
      //return your marker here
      return <Marker
        key={index}
        coordinate={{
          latitude: value.YPOINT,
          longitude: value.XPOINT,
        }}
      />
    })
}
```